# django admin inlines, a different kind

Tags: django, django-admin

```
class Parent(models.Model):
  auto_inline_data = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Child(models.Model):
  field1 = models.CharField()
  field2 = models.CharField()
```

if `auto_inline_data = true` then I need to delete the old entries and enter new entries based on some calculation.
What I have done is : in the clean method of BaseInlineFormSet I check for auto_inline_data and if true delete the old rows and create new rows.
Then in save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change) if auto_inline_data is true then return without saving the form.

Relevant Codes :

```
class ChildInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        super(ChildInlineFormSet,self).clean()
        if any(self.errors):
            return
        if parent.auto_inline_data:
            Child.objects.filter(fk=parent).delete()
            Child.objects.create(*args, **kwargs)
            Child.objects.create(*args, **kwargs)

In admin.py
class ParentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        if formset.model._meta.db_table == 'Child':
            if formset.data['auto_inline_data']:
                return
```

While saving when `old data exists and auto_inline_data is true` then I get error

```
Exception Value:'ChildFormFormSet' object has no attribute 'new_objects'
Exception Location: Python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py in construct_change_message, line 688
```

Is there any other way to achieve my objective or my code needs some modifications.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: why are you deleting the old entries and not updating the old entries?

Comment: @Thomas :number of auto entered rows may not be equal to number of existing rows